# How to escape the "dot" in id attribute?

Tags: pug

I would like my jade to compile to something like this

```
<script id="template/widget.html">
```

so in Jade I do this

```
script#template/widget.html
```

but of course that doesn't work because it thinks .html is a class. Any idea on how to this, or is it impossible to have dots in your id names.

**EDIT** I should add that I'm using jade 1.0.3 so script(id="template/widget.html") which is what I was using no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
script(id="template/widget.html")
```

Comment: Yes I agree, but unfortunately, the reason I'm doing this is I'm overwriting some Bootstrap templates so I kind of need the dot in there because they have a dot in their templates.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think you could have characters such as `/` and `.` in css identifiers.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

I would make sense if `script#template/widget.html` was being interpreted as:

`<script id="template/widget" class="html">`

As `script#myid.myclass` would be interpreted as `<script id="myid" class="myclass">`